# t.belongs_to in migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, migration

I was using Ryan Bates's [source code for railscasts](https://github.com/ryanb/railscasts-episodes/tree/master/episode-141) #141 in order to create a simple shopping cart.  In one of the migrations, he lists

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.belongs_to :category
      t.string :name
      t.decimal :price
      t.text :description
      t.timestamps
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :products
  end
end
```

Here is the Product model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :category
end
```

What is the `t.belongs_to :category` line? Is that an alias for `t.integer category_id`?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The `t.belongs_to :category` is just a [special helper method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#special-helpers) of rails passing in the association.

If you look in the [source code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/88aa2efd692619e87eee88dfc48d608bea9bcdb4/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/schema_definitions.rb#L421) `belongs_to` is actually an alias of `references`

Answer (score 21):

```
$ rails g migration AddUserRefToProducts user:references
```

this generates:

```
class AddUserRefToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :products, :user, index: true
  end
end
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#creating-a-standalone-migration

Answer (score 16):

Yes, it's an alias; It can also be written `t.references category`.

Comment: Almost. `t.references` now also adds a foreign key constraint.
https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/Table/references

Answer (score 7):

## First: the migration

`rails generate migration add_user_to_products user:belongs_to`

(in this situation) is equivalent to

`rails generate migration add_user_to_products user:references`

and both create

```
class AddUserToProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_reference :products, :user, index: true
  end
end
```

You could 'read' `add_reference :products, :user, index: true` as "products belong to user(s)"

In the schema, the migration will create a field in the `items` table called `"user_id"`. This is why the class is called `AddUserToProducts`. The migration adds the `user_id` field *to* products.

## Second: the model

He then should have updated the product model as that migration would have *only changed the schema*. He would have had to update the user model too with something like

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :products
end
```

## In general

`rails g migration add_[model linking to]_to_[table containing link] [model linking to]:belongs_to`

Note: `g` is short for `generate`

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :[table containing link]
end
```

Answer (score 4):

`add_belongs_to(table_name, *agrs)` is what you are looking for. You can read about [here](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_belongs_to)

Comment: This was the most useful to me. I used it inside a create_table block like this: t.belongs_to :user, null: false, index: { unique: true }

I wanted the index, but I needed it to force it to be unique per user

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `t.belongs_to :category` acts as an alias for `t.integer category_id`, in that it causes an appropriately typed `category_id` field to be created.

In MySQL, the migration gets me a table like this (note the `category_id` field on the second row):

```
mysql> describe products;
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| category_id | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| name        | varchar(255)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| price       | decimal(10,0) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| description | text          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at  | datetime      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at  | datetime      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```