# Rails 5: Undefined method 'image' for nil class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently, I added a blog to my web project. Now, I want to display an avatar image on the article.

I already included an avatar image for my navigation and for my services and both work, but somehow it doesn't work for my blog.

My article model:

```
belongs_to :user
```

My user model:

```
has_many :articles
```

My show.html.erb for the article:

```
<%= image_tag avatar_url(@article.user) %>
```

I added a migration `AddUserToArticles` but this didn't help me with my problem.

Create Articles Migration:

```
   class CreateArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :articles do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :description
    end
  end
end
```

#### EDIT

```
<%= @article.user.fullname %>
```

Also doesn't work.

My Application Helper:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def avatar_url(user)
    if user.image
      "https://graph.facebook.com/#{user.uid}/picture?type=large"
    else
      gravatar_id = Digest::MD5::hexdigest(user.email).downcase
      "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/#{gravatar_id}.jpg?d=identical&s=150"
    end
  end
end
```

AddUserToArticles migration:

```
class AddUserToArticles < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    add_reference :articles, :user, foreign_key: true
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you use Active Storage? Add your model code here too

Comment: No, I don't use Active Storage. Instead I use an Application Helper.

Comment: Looks like you have done migration without references

Comment: If so, you can add it like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/33101024/4453714

Comment: Yes, I thought that too, I already added a migration, but this didn't help me either.

Comment: Its better to debug this with `rails c` like `Article.last.user` and see if it returns User object

Comment: It returns nil, so probably because I created the article before I added the user references. So there shouldn't be an error anymore, after I create a new article.